# Solution when I need small links on mobile optimised site for touch screen devices?

Tags: mobile, touch-screen

Im designing a mobile optimised site and I have a space issue. I need to have a bar graph showing availability by month. If I have this laid out horizontally as in my image I think its clear on a 320px wide screen.

[image]

However I also want the months (or their corresponding bars) to be links. In the image the links would be much smaller than Apple’s recommended 44px. I may have to make the graph vertical, but im trying to find a way to avoid having to do this.

So, is there a smart solution when the necessary space for a finger tap is the limiting factor but the visual detail is fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hit something smaller than 44px, but you need feedback. Perhaps let the user drag over the bars to select the one they want, showing the selection in realtime along with a control elsewhere showing more details ("May: $500"). The more details pane could contain a link to tap on for more information.

This way they get more of a chance to precisely select the bar, since they can preview the selection.

Alternately, let them pinch-zoom?